# How to insert radio button column in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radio-button

I am having trouble inserting a radio button in gridview. I don't understand how this get's done, also i don't see item template anywhere in gridview?

Comment: A nice tutorial is here: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=5187857

Comment: sorry, i require a radion button column, i ve seen people use it with item template, i can't find the item template field anywhere in gridview either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in a RadioButton tag in the TemplateField

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="RowSelector" runat="server" GroupName="SelectGroup" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

[RadioButton columns in a gridview](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/radiobuttoningridview.html)

Comment: Thank you, this works for me, how do i manually add another column?
say a column that displays today's date and another that displays some offer

Comment: You can do this programatically by having ASP controls in the <ItemTemplate> such as <asp:Label id="lbDate" Text='<%= System.DateTime.Now.ToString() %>' runat="server" />, for more complicated custom data that doesn't directly match up to a column in your datasource  I'd recommend taking a look at the GridView.RowDataBound Event, you can access GridViewRowEventArgs data items from the datasource you are binding the grid view to and use gridview.FindControl to set controls from the code behind. See [RowDataBound](http://goo.gl/wyCxiF) and [GridViewRowEventArgs](http://goo.gl/q6FvgS)

Comment: why fields are going to be static i.e only the time will be changed.. 
3 columns -- 
radio button column || date time column of now || some text column

Comment: It totally depends on your requirements, you could have 3 TemplateFields, with the relevant controls, and use e.g Text='<%# Container.DataItem("TextContent") %>' to set the value, and avoid having to use RowDataBound, RowDataBound is used if the data is more complicated/different to a directly matched database column.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("sr_no");
        dt.Columns.Add("item_name");
        dt.Columns.Add("item_id");
        dt.Columns.Add("qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("rate");
        dt.Columns.Add("total");

        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["sr_no"] = txtSr.Text;
        dr["item_name"] = ddlItem.SelectedItem.Text;
        dr["item_id"] = ddlItem.SelectedValue;
        dr["qty"] = txtQty.Text;
        dr["rate"] = txtRate.Text;
        dr["total"] = int.Parse(txtQty.Text) * int.Parse(txtRate.Text);

        dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

i ll be using this. fyi